# Is ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {13}]$ UFD??

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I study the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {13}]$
I  want to know that it is UFD OR NOT.

My work
$12=(2)(2)(3)$ and
$12=([\sqrt {13}] +1)([\sqrt {13}]-1)$
And all these are irreducible elements. Hence not UFD

If I am wrong  then correct me...
And tell me how to do it??

Comment: Any Euclidean domain is a UFD. But, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})$ is Euclidean, so a UFD, meaning the integers of the field have the unique factorization property. However, the integers of this field are not all of the form $a+b\sqrt{13},$ for integers $a,b.$ There are also integers of the form $(a+b\sqrt{13})/2$ for odd integers $a,b.$ So, your ring contains only some of the integers of the fiels. I thimk your argument is OK (I didn't check irreducibility).

Comment: How do you know none of the factors $2,3$ are same (upto a unit) as one of $(\sqrt{13}+1)$ or $(\sqrt{13}-1)$??

Comment: Btw what is the definition of unique factorisation domain??

Comment: @ChrisLeary   $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{13}]$ is not Euclidean.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That follows pretty trivially from the fact that their norms are different, ne?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki that question was to the user who posted the question... you could have waited for some time..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I figured it was but also thought that the fact was comparatively self-evident; mea culpa.

Comment: @ChrisLeary  I do irreducibilty , from myself they are irreducible ,but not sure  about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ChrisLeary correctly notes in a comment, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{13}]$ is not integrally closed, because ${1+\sqrt{13}\over 2}$ is an algebraic integer.

By general basic algebraic number theory, the integral closure *is* a Dedekind domain, in any case. Again by generalities, a non-integrally-closed ring cannot be Dedekind, so certainly cannot be a principal ideal domain, nor a unique factorization domain. (And, thus, certainly not Euclidean in any sense.)

Comment: It means that Z√13 is not UFD?. Hence not PID,and  not Euclidean domain

Comment: Right. The non-integral-closed-ness sabotages all those properties.

Comment: @paul garrett - Thanks for filling in for me an obvious gap in my knowledge of number theory.